# How to force specific Yaml list type

Tags: python, yaml

How do you force the dump() method in Python's yaml implementation to use the one-element-per-line list style?

e.g. When I do `yaml.dump([1,2,3])` I get `"[1, 2, 3]\n"` when I actually want:

```
- 1
- 2
- 3
```

Comment: I was actually looking for the opposite, force dump in flow style. I could not find an answer in the (quite unhelpful) documentation or by looking at the (quite convoluted) source code. Thanks to the magic of Google and StackOverflow, I was able to find the answer to my related (but different) question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`default_flow_style`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#DumpingYAML):

```
>>> print yaml.dump([1,2,3], default_flow_style=False)
- 1
- 2
- 3
```